# sendmail logging error to my httpd error_log?

Tags: logging, centos, sendmail

I just had my server upgraded from Centos 4.9 to Centos 6.2

The following line is getting logged to my **/etc/httpd/logs/error_log** (no timestamp, but it gets logged at least every few seconds) :

```
sendmail: Not running with correct effective GID.  Is sendmail binary setgid mailtrap?
```

Any idea what it might be or how I could stop this error to get logged ?

---

All I could think of was doing the following... and long and behold, I get the same error:

```
root@vps1 [/]# whereis sendmail
sendmail: /usr/sbin/sendmail /usr/lib/sendmail
root@vps1 [/]# /usr/lib/sendmail stop
sendmail: Not running with correct effective GID.  Is sendmail binary setgid mailtrap?
sendmail: Not running with correct effective GID.  Is sendmail binary setgid mailtrap?
root@vps1 [/]# /usr/lib/sendmail restart
sendmail: Not running with correct effective GID.  Is sendmail binary setgid mailtrap?
sendmail: Not running with correct effective GID.  Is sendmail binary setgid mailtrap?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it for me:

```
chown root:mailtrap /usr/sbin/sendmail
chmod 2755 /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by simply rebuilding sendmail

Host support also sent me the following (might help someone else looking up this same error)

```
-bash-4.1# hostname
vps1.myhostname.com
-bash-4.1# sendmail
Exim is a Mail Transfer Agent. It is normally called by Mail User Agents,
not directly from a shell command line. Options and/or arguments control
what it does when called. For a list of options, see the Exim documentation.
-bash-4.1#
```